# Beautiful Soup scraper gives "Access Denied" even though user-agent string is specified

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website: https://www.ralphlauren.com/men?webcat=men but I don't get the HTML of the link, instead I get an HTML which states **Access to this page has been denied**.

I tried using user agent string in the header as suggested here solution: [Scraper in Python gives "Access Denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982475/scraper-in-python-gives-access-denied)

but I still get the same error.

Current Output:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<title>Access to this page has been denied.</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
url = "https://www.ralphlauren.com/men?webcat=men"

def make_soup(url):
  header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
  page = requests.get(url,headers=header)
  page_soup = soup(page.content, 'lxml')
  return page_soup 

print(make_soup(url))
```

Comment: 1: I can't reproduce, I do get back a full response. 2: the page is loaded _dynamically_ so, either way, you probably won't be able to get get the desired response. See [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: perhaps access is closed for your country, try using a proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is in cloudflare protection. You can use `cloudscraper` in lieu of `requests`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = 'https://www.ralphlauren.com/men?webcat=men'
req = scraper.get(url)
print(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
```

**Output:**

```
<Response [200]>
```